# Transformation of bases for subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Quick question: Suppose that we have a $k-$dimensional linear subspace $Z \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$, which has a basis $(v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{k})$. We can express this as a $n \times k$ matrix $V$ whose columns consist of the vectors $v_{i}$.

**Question:** Is it true that if there is another $n \times k$ matrix $M$ such that $V=M \cdot P$ for some $k \times k$ invertible matrix $P$, then if the columns of $M$ are a subset of $Z$, are they also a basis for $Z$?

Proof attempt: I will attempt to show that the columns of $M$ are linearly independent and have the same span as the columns of $V$.

1. Re-arranging the above equation gives $M=V \cdot P^{-1}$. Since $P^{-1}$ is a $k \times k$ matrix of rank $k$, then the rank of $V \cdot P^{-1}$, and hence of $M$, is equal to the rank of $V$, which is $k$. Hence, $M$ has $k$ linearly independent columns, or is of full rank.
2. $x \in span(V)$ iff $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, $x=V \cdot b$ iff $\exists b \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, $x=(M \cdot P) \cdot b$ iff $\exists b' \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$, $x=M \cdot b'$ (where $b'=P\cdot b$) iff $x \in span(M)$.

Does that prove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does this have to do with general topology or differential topology?

Comment: The above question was motivated from the definition of the orientation of a manifold, so tangentially related.